# xampp plus apache php mysql separate installers

Tags: windows, php, apache-http-server, xampp

I am wondering, having my system currently installed with XAMPP, is it okay if I will install another Apache, PHP, mySQL (separate installers)?

Answer (score 0):

you CAN but it's not recommended. because they use same port (e.g 80,443, ...) and If one of them is working , the other won't work or worse it's possible to send data to wrong program. e.g instead of sending data to original Mysql, it's possible to send them to XAMPP's mysql. **As my experience, doing such thing just confuses you, so it's better to use only one of them  and uninstall  the other one.**